# Create horizontal items control / combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-7.0

I need an item control with a *popup* (because I need to use it in a data grid so when it is expanded the column width is not affected) which presents items horizontally. Ideally, it would be a combo box with a horizontal "drop-down". Even better if it doesn't drop down but pops up above the center of the combo button (selecting the item or Esc key would close it). Items are fixed-size squares 30x30 and few in number, so a scroll view is not needed.

I found this "code" which doesn't work at all (nothing renders on the screen):

```xml
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="true"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

How to make it work?

Comment: This reads as you used ChatGPT as code writer service and now you try here. I'm not a free code writer. I'm trying to do some sort of tutoring/teaching to help people solve their problems more or less on their own. This may just a phrasing issue here with the question but the pseudo gamification you put in there also does not help either. Maybe retry asking?

Comment: Why don't you simply modify the original ControlTemplate? This gives all the freedom to position the flyout where ever you want.

Comment: @BionicCode. I never done that before I have no idea how to position the popup. I modified the code a little and now it does what I want but now the popup stays on the same position on the screen while the parent window moves. it looks weird. I am obv not up to it.

Comment: I think it would be easier to figure out this problem from scratch than to understand what ChatGPT generated.

Comment: I agree. I posted the code because many people down vote because they ask - what have you done first.. but then there are others who would downvote anyway.. its no win no win environment

Answer (score 0):

This Behaviour should solve the popup positioning problem.

```
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace MCS.UI.WpfUICommon.AttachedProperties
{
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public class AutoRepositionPopupBehavior : Behavior<Popup>
{
    private const int WM_MOVING = 0x0216;

    // should be moved to a helper class
    private DependencyObject GetTopmostParent(DependencyObject element)
    {
        var current = element;
        var result = element;

        while (current != null)
        {
            result = current;
            current = (current is Visual || current is Visual3D) ?
               VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current) :
               LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        //AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += (sender, e) => Update();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (GetTopmostParent(AssociatedObject.PlacementTarget) is Window root)
            {
                var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(root);
                var hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);
                if (hwndSource != null)
                {
                    hwndSource.AddHook(HwndMessageHook);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private IntPtr HwndMessageHook(IntPtr hWnd,
            int msg, IntPtr wParam,
            IntPtr lParam, ref bool bHandled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_MOVING)
        {
            Update();
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // force the popup to update it's position
        var mode = AssociatedObject.Placement;
        AssociatedObject.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
        AssociatedObject.Placement = mode;
    }
}
}
```

And the usage in xaml:

```
         xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" 
         xmlns:attachedprops="clr-namespace:YourBehaviourNameSpace"

 <Popup .... >
    <b:Interaction.Behaviors>                      
        <attachedprops:AutoRepositionPopupBehavior/>
    </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Popup>
```

Comment: thank you. thats very neat. however I would just like to know - how "native" wpf combo works? I cant believe it needs that much code including windows message pump processing to just keep a popup in place.